# How to decrypt ECDHM SSL traffic?

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2, ecdsa

I am trying to decrypt some TLSv1.2 traffic with Java. I have some information from Wireshark like so...

[image]

Any advice on how i might approach this? Let's assume i already have packet data in java i want to decrypt.

Comment: Raw packet data isn't going to help you unless you have the keys in question, including the session ones.

Comment: i have the session keys too